# Ionic + React.js: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am utilizing firebase for the database and Ionic + React for mobile app. I already converted my firebase data into array but when I want to map the values. It tells me that it should have a unique key, but I already put a unique key in my return function in the element. Can someone tell me what did I do wrong? Thanks.

Here is my code in converting objects to array

```
const Tab2: React.FC = () => {
  const [doctors, setDoctor] = React.useState([]);

  useIonViewWillEnter(()=>{
    console.log('Enter')
    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('type').equalTo('doctor').on('value',(snapshot)=>{
          setDoctor(Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(key => ({ [key]: snapshot.val()[key] })))
        })
    console.log(doctors)

  })
```

And in my return

```
        <IonList>
        {doctors.map(elem => {
            return(
              <IonItem key={elem['uid']}>
              <IonLabel>
                <IonText className="font-weight: bold;">
                <h3>{elem['name']}</h3>
                </IonText>
                <h4>{elem['speciality']}</h4>
                <h4>{elem['email']}</h4>
              </IonLabel>
              <br></br>
            </IonItem> 
            )
          })}
        </IonList>
```

What I got is `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

My firebase structure

[image]

Update: the `console.log(doctors)` will only output an empty array like this `[]` and i dont know why. I already put it in a method before the component enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: thats just a warning, not an error.*

This is the right approach.

```
<IonList>
  {doctors.map((elem, index) => {
    // index has to come from the second parameter from map
    
    return (
      <IonItem key={index}>
        <IonLabel>
          <IonText className="font-weight: bold;">
            <h3>{elem["name"]}</h3>
          </IonText>
          <h4>{elem["speciality"]}</h4>
          <h4>{elem["email"]}</h4>
        </IonLabel>
        <br></br>
      </IonItem>
    );
  })}
</IonList>;
```

The index must be placed in the first/parent div element. In this case it will be `<IonItem>`

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Also as per you're not getting the data. Adjust your code like so. You just have to create a new arr, and move through snapshot to get a key.

pushing the object with the respective key to a new arr, so it can be iterable without specific key names such as *eA9w5ynhqN9iT7kKDBt2Ane9VF3*

```
useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
  console.log("Enter");
  let newArr = [];
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("users")
    .orderByChild("type")
    .equalTo("doctor")
    .on("value", (snapshot) => {
      let key;
      snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
        key = childSnap.key; // im just getting the key
        const snapVal = snapshot.val(); // getting the object
        newArr.push(snapVal[key]); 
      });
      setDoctor(newArr);

      // console.log(doctors)
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks sir, it got no error but the `console.log(doctors)` thing is logging an `[]` even i put it in `ionViewWIllEnter` maybe the array is not yet populated?

Comment: put a `console.log(doctors)` before the return method before `<IonList>` and share what you're getting.

Comment: cool, i know what the issue is post your data shape in the post please :) pretty much in  a nutshell, the iae... key must be removed.

Comment: what do you mean sir? can we chat about this thing?

Comment: so copy paste the result, and post the code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219752/discussion-between-barnowl-and-vince).

Answer (score 0):

try adding the `key` prop to each child as well as each element inside children and it will work.

your code should look like this:

```
<IonList>
    {doctors.map(elem => {
        return(
          <IonItem key={elem['uid']}>
          <IonLabel key={"lbl-" + elem['uid']}>
            <IonText key={"txt-"+elem['uid']}className="font-weight: bold;">
            <h3 key={"name-"+elem['uid']}>{elem['name']}</h3>
            </IonText>
            <h4 key={"speciality-"+elem['uid']}>{elem['speciality']}</h4>
            <h4 key={"email-"+elem['uid']}>{elem['email']}</h4>
          </IonLabel>
          <br></br>
        </IonItem> 
        )
      })}
</IonList>
```

if you noticed i added lbl-, txt- before the key and that to avoid another warning:
"Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key,

Comment: what do you mean sir? can you give an example?